# DAX formula / Power BI calculation : calculate Quarter 3 from 2 different tables (Actual and Estimate)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I hope you can help me with below matter. I am trying to figure out a calculation for Quarter 3 (July + Aug + Sept).
I have 2 tables Actual and Estimate, the data in Actual is till August 2021. When calculating Quarter 3 I need to get July and Aug data from Actual table and Sept data from Estimate table.
When the Actual tables gets loaded with the Sept data it should shift from Estimate to Actual. Similar calculation for the next Quarter 4 (Oct + Nov + Dec).

Appreciate your help in this matter.

Thank you.

Attached below image for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5yK.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a new table using this 2 tables. If I understand you correct, create the table as below-

```
select all records from "Actual Data" except months March, June, September and December.

union all

select all records from "Estimate Data" only for months March, June, September and December.
```

Now do your calculation from the new table.

Comment: Creating a table will not help, When I get actual data for September it should point to the Actual table instead of Estimate table

Comment: You need advance transformation to get your desired result. You can create a new table like- add records from Estimate table if the month is not available in Actual. And then do you calculation.